# How to include a chemical reaction in the equation numbering?

Tags: equations, numbering, chemistry

I would like to have my chemical reaction as equation number 0.1 and the equation (K_D) as an equation with the second number 0.2.

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\ch{S + E <>[ $k_{\mathrm{SI}}$ ][ $k_{\mathrm{IS}}$ ] E.I <>[ $k_{\mathrm{PI}}$ ][ $k_{\mathrm{IP}}$ ] P + E}
\begin{align*}

\begin{equation} \label{}
 K_{D} = \frac{[A][B]^{N_{max}}}{[AB_{N_{max}]}} = \frac{k_{off}}{k_{on}}.
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

With Alex's suggestion I got this: [image]

This is the SOLUTION:

```
\begin{equation}
  \ch{ A + B -> C + D }
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing code with your question. However, at present it does not compile. For completeness and later reference, could you add the `\documentclass` and the `\usepackage`s?

Answer (score 2):

[image]You can use numberwithin{equation}{section}:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{chemmacros}
    \begin{document}

    \numberwithin{equation}{section}
    \begin{align}
        \ch{S + E <>[ $k_{\mathrm{SI}}$ ][ $k_{\mathrm{IS}}$ ] E.I <>[                 $k_{\mathrm{PI}}$ ][ $k_{\mathrm{IP}}$ ] P + E}
    \end{align}

    \begin{equation} \label{}
         K_{D} = \frac{[A][B]^{N_{max}}}{[AB_{N_{max}]}} = \frac{k_{off}}        {k_{on}}.
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: @Marijn, I added the document class and the packages required to compile.

Comment: unfortunately your solution only provides the numbering expansion of the existing equation numbering

Comment: indeed your example works, but when I transpose it to my case then its not working. See image posted in the question

Comment: solution posted in main question window

Comment: @Mathy, are you adding any \section or \subsection? I don't see a reason to have 0.2.1 instead of 0.1. And why is your first equation without number? Did you see that (in my answer) I removed the asterisks from the align environment?

Comment: indeed my equations are written in different sections and subsections